# MySQL query - Find all records for which there are more than one distinct value

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to select values from one table, for which there is *more* than one distinct value for a specific attribute in another table.

I feel like it should be something like this, but I can't seem to get it to work:

```
SELECT * value1
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT value2) > 1
```

OK, for example:

```
table1        table2
id   name     id   hobby
1     a       1     x
2     b       1     x
3     c       3     y
4     d       4     z
```

So I want to select all names that have more than one hobby (in this case name a).

I appreciate this is not fully normalised and very over simplified, but I can't seem to work out how to express 'more than one occurrence' of a value for another value in SQL.

Comment: value2 is in table 1 ?

Comment: No, value2 is on table2

Answer (score 0):

Try with a Group By clause:

```
SELECT * value1
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.id
Group By table1.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT value2) > 1
```

Also stated in the comment, is Value2 part of Table1 or Table2?

Answer (score 0):

Since we don't know the exact structure of your tables ...here is my best guess. Please test it and let me know .

```
select *     
  From   table1 a , (select id , value2  from table2   
  Group  By id , value2 HAVING COUNT(value2) > 1 ) b 
  where  a.id = b.id1
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO you'd better to use the following strategy:

1. Look for data from `table2 JOIN table1`
2. From #1 set, compute `value2` occurrences for each couple `value2`/`id`
3. Finally keep only records where these occurences > 1

So you might try this:

```
SELECT T2.COUNT(*) AS `count`, T2.value2, T1.*
FROM table2 T2
  JOIN table1 T1 ON T1.id = T2.id
GROUP BY T2.value2, T2.id
WHERE `count` > 1
```

BTW note that I didn't include anything about `value1`, since I don't see, not only how it can be involved in your issue, but also what it might signify the way it appears in your query example.